# How to send image through bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my application, I open my gallery and pick a picture and then show my image in an image view then I'm supposed to send it through bluetooth.

That's what i've reached :

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
iv.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
```

How to send it through bluetooth?

N.B I've opened my bluetooth and made it also discover-able by other devices . 
Please I'll be thankful if u helped me in my assignment =]